# Ajax abrindo conteúdo sem refresh

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilo_principal.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
        <meta name="Description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js_principal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#inline a").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');
                  $("#conteudo").load(this.href);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Josino Ribeiro - Assessoria e Marketing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="p0">
            <div id="p1">
                <header>
                  <div id="header">
                    <img width="121px" height="157px" src="imagens/logo.png" id="imgLogo" />
                  </div>
                  <div id="p101midias">
                            <div class="midias" id="instagram"></div>
                            <div class="midias" id="youtube"></div>
                            <div class="midias" id="twitter"></div>
                            <div class="midias" id="facebook"></div>
                        </div>
                </header>
                <nav>
                  <div id="caixamenu">
                    <ul class="inline">
                      <li class="menuLi"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="menuLi"><a href="paginas/josino.php"> Josino Ribeiro</a></li>
                      <li class="menuLi"><a href="#"> Serviços</a></li>
                      <li class="menuLi"><a href="#"> Clientes</a></li>
                      <li class="menuLi"><a href="#"> Contatos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="row-fluid" id="conteudo">
                      <div class="span6" id="esquerdo"> <img width="323px" height="434px" src="imagens/logo-middle.png" id="imgLogo"></div>
                      <div class="span6" id="direito">
                        <img src="imagens/img_min_1.png" id="min01">
                        <img src="imagens/img_min_2.png" id="min02">
                        <img src="imagens/img_min_3.png" id="min03">
                      </div>

                </div>

                <div id="Rodape1" class="span12">
                  <div id="escrita" class="span12">
                      <p align="left">
                        Josino Ribeiro - Assessoria e Marketing<br>
                        josino.ribeiro.ribeiro@hotmail.com<br>
                        (31) 8786 4013  </div>
                      </p>
                  <div id="logo" class="span12">
                    <img src="imagens/logo_ops.png" id="logoOps">
                    <img src="imagens/logo_hot_systems.png" id="logoHot">
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div id="RodapeC">
                    <div id="Rodape">© Josino Ribeiro Comunicações - Todos os direitos reservados</div>
                  </div> <!-- Fim rodape -->
            </div> <!-- Fim p1 -->
        </div> <!-- Fim p0 -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Quero que abra o conteúdo das páginas na minha tag com id `#conteudo`, porém não está funcionando.

Comment: E qual é o erro que te dá? Não devia ser só `href` aqui: `.load(this.href);` ?

Comment: Ele não da erro, apenas nao carrega a pagina que eu quero.

Comment: Esta linha não está a ser usada: `var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');` podes tirar e junta `/` no inicio de cada link para garantir que ele começa da root. E sim, coloca o link do site online para vermos.

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console do navegador?

Answer (score 1):

Na função .load, você está passando parâmetro errado para ser carregado

```
$("#conteudo").load(this.href);
```

mude para

```
$("#conteudo").load(href);
```

Answer (score 0):

É provável que o endereço gerado aqui `var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');` seja inacessível ou o `this.href` seja o caminho errado.

Troque isto:

```
var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');
$("#conteudo").load(this.href);
```

Por isto:

```
var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');
$("#conteudo").load(href);
```

Ou então troque `.load` por `.ajax`:

Primeiro tente isto (usando this.href):

```
var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');
$.ajax(this.href, {
  "cache": false,
  "dataType": "html"
}).done(function(data) {
     $("#conteudo").html(data);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
     $("#conteudo").html(status + ": " + error);
});
```

Se não funcionar tente isto (usando var href):

```
var href = "/paginas/"+$(this).attr('href');
$.ajax(href, {
  "cache": false,
  "dataType": "html"
}).done(function(data) {
     $("#conteudo").html(data);
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
     $("#conteudo").html(status + ": " + error);
});
```

Após ler a resposta do próprio autor, notei que ele usou `$("#inline a")` quando o correto seria `$(".inline a")`, pois representa este elemento `<ul class="inline">`.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o erro era bem pequeno, em ver de colocar
`#conteudo`, ou deveria ter colocado `.conteudo`, porque o .(ponto) é um seletor para classe e o # para o id, então o correto é:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".inline a").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var href = $(this).attr('href');
                  $("#conteudo").load(this.href);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Você disse #conteudo, mas na pergunta está correto #conteudo, o que mudou foi o #inline: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66464/3635