# Carregar página sem carregar player de música

Tags: php, html5, ajax

Estou fazendo um site onte tenho um player de música em **HTML5**, só que toda vez que troco a página o player carrega novamente. Em minhas pesquisa parece que existe tudas soluções ou **AJAX** ou **IFRAME**. IFRAME dizem que não é muito recomendado então pensei em fazer com AJAX, mas como não sei usar AJAX, então recorri ao goole, só que tudo que encontrei foi como dar refresh em um conteúdo sem dar na página.
O que eu quero é o contrário a página toda pode recarregar mas o player não, para assim continuar tocando as músicas.

Encontrei este post [Ajax abrindo conteúdo sem refresh](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66457/ajax-abrindo-conte%C3%BAdo-sem-refresh) mas não atendeu ao que eu queria

OBS: O player está dentro de um include de php, tem problema isso?

Answer (score 1):

Opa, no seu caso você teria que fazer um ajax que daria o refresh na página menos no player.
Unica solução.

Se apertarem F5 não tem como fugir, você poderia usar algo com lazyload para o player mas dai seria o contrario, ele carregaria a pagina e o player ficaria dependendo de uma ação do usuário para carregar como clicar em um botão por exemplo.

Comment: Guerra         Então e se eu colocasse todo conteúdo do site na mesma página e fizesse o menu em ajax como eu faria isto?

Comment: é complicadinho, o ideal a grosso modo seria subdivir em divs e carregar o conteudo de cada um individualmente por ajax, para facilitar o seu layout. Digamos que está no meio, então seriam 4 "divs" cima baixo esquerda e direita, dai vc faria seu servidor php responder uma solicitação ajax retornando o conteudo dessas divs.

Comment: Guerra         então deixa pq eu não sei ajax e não tenho tempo pra aprender agora pq eu preciso entregar o projeto. Ainda se tivesse um exemplo por ai na internet mas o máximo que eu achei foi esse site feito em bootstrap http://www.thiagobrava.com.br/

Comment: para q vc quer q o usuario navegue pelo site sem a musica parar certo?, nesse caso o ideal é um iframe mesmo =b

Answer (score 0):

É uma mistura de carregar o novo conteúdo via Ajax e utilizar uma API do HTML5 chamada History.

[Esta pergunta semelhante no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929136/266569) vai te dar um Norte pra seguir.